# Change color theme when battery saver mode is active

Tags: battery, nexus-5, notification-bar, color, navigation-bar

I'm using a Nexus 5 with stock ROM. When the battery saver mode activates, the notification and navigation bar's color turn to a bright orange. I find this color very distracting.

Is it possible to change the color?

Comment: Please share device/Android information.

Comment: I think specific ROMs grant this feature, or maybe a mod can work, but you have to be rooted for both.

Comment: @SarpSTA Sure. Done.

Comment: You can try to edit the SystemUI.apk or framework-res.apk to change the colors.. And BTW, the Xposed module named '**GravityBox**' has an option to disable the orange color when Battery Saver is ON.

Comment: @GokulNC thanks for the tip about Xposed and GravityBox. Please add this as an answer so I can accept it.